# R: remove row clusters of repeated elements in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with 2 columns where the second column can have binary values (1 or 2). I would like to remove randomly clusters of rows where the second column is always 2.

example:

```
df1<-data.frame(x=seq(10),y=c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2))
[1] df1

    x y
1   1 1
2   2 2
3   3 2
4   4 1
5   5 2
6   6 2
7   7 1
8   8 2
9   9 1
10 10 2
```

given 2 as cluster size, there are two clusters: A: rows 2 and 3 and B: row 5 and 6. I would like to remove  50% of clusters randomly which mean delete rows 2 and 3 or 5 and 6

Desired output:

```
    x y
1   1 1
4   4 1
5   5 2
6   6 2
7   7 1
8   8 2
9   9 1
10 10 2
```

I tried this but does not work:

```
cluster_size=2
percentage_clusters_to_remove= 0.5
clusters<-which(df1$y==rep(cluster_size,2))
remove<-sample(clusters, length(clusters)*percentage_clusters_to_remove)
df2<-df1[-c(remove),]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` 
 Like this?

```
df1%>%
  slice(-sample(which(y==2), round(length(which(df1$y==2))*0.5,0)) )
```

Comment: No sorry, this just remove one row. Does not generate the 'desire output' suggested in the question